# why can I not find .jar files in my android eclipse project?

Tags: android

I placed 3 jar files in the libs folder of my Android project. Yet  I can not find them in eclipse, when I go to:

project - properties - java build path - libraries tab  <-- those jar files are not there.

Can you tell me why this is ?

Answer (score 1):

in `Eclipse`, `package explorer`, you should have `Android Dependecies`. Open it and you should found there  your jars

Answer (score 0):

You can't install jar files on Andriod devices but you can include jar as library in your application.Android can run Java apps but they have to be compiled in a .apk file rather than a .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you aren't adding a library, your importing a jar. It's something complete different. Right click your project and select the option to import a jar. A file picker will show up, then browse to your jar and click ok.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the jar file then Buildpath -> Add to Build path click

try this